# Flexbox issues with https in IE10, Windows 7

Tags: css, wordpress, http, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am having issues with IE10 when using flexbox 2012 syntax as fallback for IE10, the weird thing is that I am only experiencing issues when https is used and not with http. Everything looks good with the http protocol in the same browser (IE10, win7).

This is an example of the code I am using, works in almost every browser.

```
.flex-container{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Is there any solution?

Edit:
I know this sounds like a caching issue, but I have inactivated the server cache and cleared the browser cache several times. No differences. IE10 is running in standards mode.

Comment: What do you mean with blocked? Requests or CSS/Script requests? All styles and scripts is being loaded correctly when http or https is being used.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. No all scripts/styles should be loaded with its http protocol that is used. Though images and other links could be different, but that shouldnt cause problems like this right?